# Store Images in datastore from local drive in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I couldn't find articles match to my requirements.

Basically, what I want is that:

1. User uploads picture to the application from their local drive.
2. Application stores the picture uploaded to datastore.
3. Application retrieves images from datastore.

Any suggestions? Urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in much the same way as you would in any other framework or platform: Create an HTML form with a 'file' input and the mimetype set to 'multipart/form-data'. On the server side, extract the file data from the form field (using `self.request.POST['fieldname'].value` in webapp) and store the contents in a datastore model, in a `db.BlobProperty` field.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what is discussed in [the documentation for the BlobStore API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html).

Comment: Except it's storing the data in the blobstore, not the datastore.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The datastore is limited to byte arrays of 1MB. I'm not sure it's the best place to store images from end users.

Comment: I agree, Blobstore is a better choice. I assumed the user was aware of it and wanted a datastore-specific option, but I could well be wrong.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the suggestions and opinions...No, as long as the images can be stored on database of GAE environment. It doesn't matter whether it's datastore or blobstore. Thanks again!